# Select table rows without table headers using css selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, click, css-tables

Using css selector how am i supposed to write a selector so that only table rows that have data display cursor as pointer. I tried below but nope

```
table tbody tr:not(tr>th)
```

is this cross browser and works event in IE6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not a valid CSS selector; you can't put combinators inside `:not()`.

Your best bet is to put header rows (i.e. `<tr>` elements that contain `<th>` elements) inside a `<thead>`, leave the rest of the rows in your table's `<tbody>`, and simply use this:

```
table tbody tr {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

If you can't modify your HTML, it's not possible with CSS selectors alone, especially not with your requirement of supporting IE6. Use JavaScript instead; here's an obligatory jQuery example:

```
$('table tbody tr:not(:has(th))').css('cursor', 'pointer');
```

Comment: @BoltClock since we are using the styles for Gridview (a asp.net control) we got pretty much no choice ;( they don't render `th` inside `thead`

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Then I'm afraid you won't get anywhere with CSS selectors, especially not with IE6 support. See my edit.

Answer (score 5):

***Assuming*** that your header row will **always** be the first row, you could do this:

```
table tr:not(:first-child) {
    background:red;
}​
```

This selects all `tr` elements **except** the `first-child` (as in, the first of the matched elements).

This *does not* work in IE6 or any other version of IE except IE9.

But yes, if you do require IE6 support, Javascript must be used.

Comment: You can cater for IE7 and IE8 using `table tr + tr` instead, but IE6 is beyond reach.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using <thead> tag.

In my case table looks like:

```
<table>
  <thead> <tr><th>... </thead>
  <tbody> <tr><td>... </tbody>
</table>
```

this will be applied for all tables:

```
tbody tr{
      background: yellow;
}
```

this is only for tables which has header:

```
thead+tbody tr{
      background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically I tried solutions above but in my case I wrote something different to make it works. I don't know if it's better to use `:hover` or not for cursor.

```
table tbody>tr:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

In my case table is coded like that

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>...</tr>
     ....
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>...</tr>
    ...
</table>
```

At all, I wanted to add style to entire line and not `tr` themselves